# How to extract filename from askopenfile result?

Tags: python, tkinter

I do my first stumbling in Python/Tkinter. When I choose a file to be opened, I do:

```
filein = askopenfile(initialdir=initial_dir, filetypes=mask, mode='r')
```

It's ok, but my filein consists the string below:

```
open file '/home/steve/projects/python/test/myfile', mode 'r' at 0xb7494a70
```

Is any method to get the choosen filename without the garbage I do not need?

Comment: I'm willing to bet your `filein` doesn't consist of a string, but of a file object, whose repr is a string that contains that substring inside angle brackets. And that isn't "garbage you do not need", it's part of the representation of a file object, and if it didn't exist, you wouldn't be able to do things like, say, read the file…

Comment: "my filein consists the string below: ..." **No**. The `filein` is **not** a string, it's a file object. If you want to read the file you can simply do `filein.read()`. If you want to write to it just do `filein.write(...)`. It *would have been* a string if you used `askopenfilename`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `file` object. You can use `filein.name` to get the name of the file. Alternatively, you can replace the call with `askopenfilename()` to just get the filename if that is what you are after.

Comment: That's the stuff! My question was not exact, I'm not distinguished terms as would be necessary, but luckily you understood what I mean. Thanks!